# PyGame window closes seconds after opening without input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So here's the problem: I am starting to use PyGame 1.9.6 on Python 3.8 and I wrote the following program.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode( (500, 500) )
```

When I run it, the following happens:

1. The Python shell opens and a little PyGame message appears as expected.
2. A project window appears, but with a green border.
3. Within two seconds, the window closes.

Is this an error in my code? Or is it possible to be a problem of my setup? I already reinstalled PyGame and nothing changed... Maybe it's because I'm using such a recent version of Python, even though the PyGame FAQ says that:

Pygame 1.9.2 [my version is 1.9.6] supports Python 3.2 and up.

Comment: Why would you expect the window to stay open?  Your program *ends* immediately after creating the window, I'm surprised you're even seeing it for two seconds.

Comment: @jasonharper Does that mean that I have to write the closing condition first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a main loop.

Can you try with this:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode( (500, 500) )

while True:
    pass
```

It won't do much, but the windows will stay open until you close it.